# chunked list throws 'zip argument #2 must support iteration' when creating multiple dicts

Tags: python-3.x, list, python-itertools

I have an issue converting a chunked list into multiple dictionaries in order to send my request batched:

```
fd = open(filename, 'r')
sqlFile = fd.read()
fd.close()
commands = sqlFile.split(';')
for command in commands:
    try:
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute(command)

        // create a list with the query results with batches of size 100
        for batch in grouper(c.fetchall(),100):
            // This is where the error occurs:
            result = [dict(zip([key[0] for key in c.description], i)) for i in batch]
            # TODO: Send the json with 100 items to API
        
    except RuntimeError:
        print('Error.')
```

The issue is that it only iterates through the batches once and gives the following error. Actually, the number of rows are 167. So there should be a result of 100 items to be sent in a first request, while the second iteration should contain 67 items to be sent in a second request.

```
TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by making a dictionary right away with `c.rowfactory = makeDictFactory(c)`:

```
def makeDictFactory(cursor):
columnNames = [d[0] for d in cursor.description]
def createRow(*args):
    return dict(zip(columnNames, args))
return createRow

def getAndConvertDataFromDatabase:(filename)
fd = open(filename, 'r')
sqlFile = fd.read()
fd.close()
commands = sqlFile.split(';')
for command in commands:
    try:
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute(command)
        c.rowfactory = makeDictFactory(c)
        data = c.fetchall()
        for batch in [data[x:x+100] for x in range(0, len(data), 100)]:
        return postBody(json.dumps(batch,default = myconverter), dataList[filename])
    except RuntimeError:
        print('Error.')
```